# How to hide oracle database password in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Instead of giving password, how can I hide the password in the shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus -S -L USERNAME/PASSWORD@"SERVICE_NAME" <<EOF
set feedback off trimspool on

SELECT * FROM TABLE;

spool off;
EXIT
EOF
```

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: It violates just about every sane rule against disclosing passwords to consider placing a password in a shell script. That said, the general approach is to include the credentials in a separate file that is only readable by the user who the script runs as and to source the credentials file from a location where no-one but the user has access. That is not a way to do it completely safe, It is just the safest way to do something unsafe the most safely.

Comment: More suitable for security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:

```
echo -n "Enter password: "
read -s passwd
echo

sqlplus -s -S << EOF
  USERNAME/${passwd}@"SERVICE_NAME"

  select something from dual;

  exit;
EOF
```

A neat side effect of this is that the password is also hidden from the OS using ps -efx.